# How to find a person and count the number of people they manage?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select count(m.emp_id), m.EMP_ID
from employee e join employee m
on e.SUPERIOR_EMP_ID = m.EMP_ID
group by m.EMP_ID;
```

I can get `m.emp_id` to show, but I need `m.Name`. Any tips?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing your database structure, and even then, you'd receive more detailed answers if you have a specific error.

Answer (score 1):

To also see `m.Name`, you just need to add `m.Name` to your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.  That said, I don't think your logic is quite right.  You want a `COUNT(e.Emp_ID)` to get the number of employees per manager:

```
SELECT     COUNT(e.Emp_ID), m.Emp_ID, m.Name
FROM       Employee e
INNER JOIN Employee m on e.Superior_Emp_ID = m.Emp_ID
GROUP BY   m.Emp_ID, m.Name
```

If you don't care about seeing the manager's employee ID, you can remove that from your select and simply view the name:

```
SELECT     COUNT(e.Emp_ID), m.Name
FROM       Employee e
INNER JOIN Employee m on e.Superior_Emp_ID = m.Emp_ID
GROUP BY   m.Name
```

And maybe give it some aliases so it makes more sense to a reader:

```
SELECT     mng.Name as "Manager", COUNT(emp.Emp_ID) as "Number of Employees"
FROM       Employee emp
INNER JOIN Employee mng on emp.Superior_Emp_ID = mng.Emp_ID
GROUP BY   mng.Name
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Comment: @icecreamguy12 No prob.. did this solve your question?